# AngularJS ng-repeat model value preassigned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have below HTML template and some data to show in inputs. I like to show these data in the template when it loads

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="option in optionslist">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label>Airline</label>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-options="airline.id as airline.name for airline in airlinesList"
                                    ng-model="selected.airline" ng-change="selectedAirlines(airline, $index)">
                                <option value="">Choose Airline</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label>Cost</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Cost" ng-model="selected.cost"
                                   ng-blur="travelCost(cost, $index)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label>Discount</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount" ng-model="selected.discount"
                                   ng-blur="travelDiscount(discount, $index)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to pre populate below serviceData values in the above template.

```
$scope.optionslist = [1, 2];
$scope.selected ={};
$scope.serviceData = [
                    {
                        "airline": 3,
                        "cost": 12345,
                        "discount": 3212

                    },
                    {
                        "airline": 1,
                        "cost": 4321,
                        "discount": 213

                    }
                ];
```

Here is the ng-options list

```
$scope.airlinesList = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": 'Emirates Airline'
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": 'Saudi Arabian Airlines'
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": 'Qatar Airways'
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": 'AirAsia'
        }
    ];
```

Comment: You should assign model values in controller when page loads. There is no other way of doing that. Angular js is client side programming. There is another way what I'd done. I `json_encode` data from server request and save them under `window` object. When `ng-app` initiliazed, I assigned these values in prespective models.

Comment: Why aren't you repeating over `serviceData` instead of `optionsList`? Not entirely clear what you are wanting. Create a demo in plunker along with better explanation of expectations

Comment: How Can I update the model with values in the ng-repeat

Comment: Here is the link

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gtf1Hesril52NsHuscGU?p=preview

I want to update the model when I clicked the preset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ng-repeat and binding everything to same selected object. Selected should be an array of objects.

```
$scope.selected = [{
    "airline": 3,
    "cost": 12345,
    "discount": 3212
  }, {
    "airline": 1,
    "cost": 4321,
    "discount": 213
  }];
```

If you set the selected array as above it will prepopulate the form if you are binding to the array like this:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-options="airline.id as airline.name for airline in airlinesList" 
         ng-model="selected[$index].airline" ng-change="selectedAirlines(airline, $index)">
     <option value="">Choose Airline</option>
 </select>
```

You need to bind to `selected[$index]` in each input field you are using.

Here's a plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/aLQcU0Y2vgNRUpev66yg?p=preview